# What is RPROVIDES for uhttpd in core-image-sato?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to include uhttpd package in poky, I included uhttpd package in poky.  meta-openembedded/meta-webserver/recipes-httpd/uhttpd this is where I have added but I am facing the following error.Please help me to solve this issue.

**ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'uhttpd'** (but /home/aa/poky/meta/recipes-sato/images/core-image-sato.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)

**NOTE**: Runtime target 'uhttpd' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['uhttpd']

**ERROR**: Required build target 'core-image-sato' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['core-image-sato', 'uhttpd']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yocto has layers which provide additional packages so its always good to search it on layerindex

http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/recipes/

Enter the regexp for recipe you are looking for 'uhttp'

This will show you which layer provides the recipe

then clone the layer containing the recipe

```
cd poky
git clone git://github.com/kraj/meta-openwrt

cd poky/build
bitbake-layers add-layer ../meta-openwrt
```

then retry to build. Now its possible that you will run into further errors but this on should be taken care of.

Comment: Thanks @Khem.I tried meta-openwrt but end-up with the following error.Thats why i tried to take uhttpd in poky directly.                                       **ERROR:** rpi-hwup-image-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Function failed: do_rootfs
**ERROR:** Logfile of failure stored in: /home/aa/poky/rpi-build/tmp/work/raspberrypi_cm3-poky-linux-gnueabi/rpi-hwup-image/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.2546
**ERROR:** Task (/home/aa/poky/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-core/images/rpi-hwup-image.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'

Comment: Can you post full build log somewhere ?

Comment: [build_log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1StDMMss9LdhvtwpHSB5dj3rqZDz-LD2s/view?usp=sharing) .Please find the log and help me to solve this issue,thanks.

Comment: here is error "file /etc/sysctl.conf conflicts between attempted installs of procps-3.3.12-r0.cortexa7hf_neon_vfpv4 and base-files-3.0.14-r89.raspberrypi_cm3" what this means is that sysctl.conf is being installed by two recipes procps and basefiles which is not right. so please find out why and remove it in one of these two recipes in do_install()

Comment: Thanks @Khem I crossed this error by deleting sysctl.conf in procps-3.3.12.Now some other issues are coming [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UGMdFOO8detqpDO_5yVfZcqy1bu9_wbc/view?usp=sharing) I have posted the log .Please help.

Comment: try setting SORT_PASSWD_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND = "" in local.conf